# How to import Other Payroll Item data

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I am trying to find documentation that details how to import 'Other Payroll Items' data to Quickbooks Payroll. I would like to import quantities for non-taxable items such as mileage and lodging. So far, I have not been able to find any information on these processes. My target is Quickbooks Desktop with the Web Connector. Does anyone have experience with this and could give me a few pointers, maybe just a place in the SDK documentation I should be using to get started? Third party tools would also be acceptable, but I would like to provide the connection from our web app to QB desktop. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payroll requests are very limited. You can enter some wage information, employee information and timetracking, but that is about all that is exposed on the payroll side through the SDK. Here is the On Screen Reference Guide - http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html - make sure you enable compatibility mode to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusions. I was given an example of another application that was able to transfer mileage and lodging (Other payroll items), but I was never able to determine how they accomplished it. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: @CyDharttha Did you figure out what can/can't be done? Can you point to message names you used from QBXML to do this?