# How to import payroll data in Quick books?

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks

I am trying to import payroll data to quickbooks. I am using c#, and i think there are two ways to do it one is create Excel file and other is IIF file.

I but both will not handle error, I want best solution for this. Can some one help me with this.

I found this ans from previously asked question, but its not clear.

question link :-[How to import Other Payroll Item data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538063/how-to-import-other-payroll-item-data)
ans:-
http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

I just want to give user file which they can use for importing.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an Excel file means to import and not export. Your request is contradictory.
maybe this link helps:
http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/pages/inproducthelp/core/qb2k12/contentpackage/thirdparty/excel/ov_msimport.html

Comment: Forntana:- There is no specific format they have mentioned, I have to create list of users and their payroll info. But if i dont know fields I cant create Excel File for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar problem right now, so a few points of clarity:

1) Quickbooks Desktop allows an import of an IIF file. An IIF file is basically a fancy Tab-separated file (.tsv) with a few extra headers that need special formatting.

2) They do not import any other formats (.xlsx, .csv) for Quickbooks Desktop.

3) The answer that OP references is to using an SDK used by developer. Using Excel or an IIF file means that you will NOT be using an SDK.

I know this answer is 3 years late, but this link has the formatting kit for the IIF imports.
https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Getting-Started/IIF-Overview-import-kit-sample-files-and-headers/m-p/201577

From this resource, and understanding how the IIF works, the specific answer to your question is:

1. Please define "Payroll Data" better"? Is that a Journal Entry, or
   a Bank Transfer, or what accounting tool are you caring about? There are many to choose from, including Bill Related, Cash Sale, Credit Memo, Depoit, Invoice, Item Receipt, Journal Entry, Purchase Order, Receive Payment, Statement Charge, Timer Activity, Transfer, and others depending on your version of QuickBooks Desktop.
2. If you just care about making sure that the employees are in there, the
   IIF formatting kit tells us that it would involve this format:

=====================

```
!EMP    NAME    REFNUM  TIMESTAMP   INIT    ADDR1   ADDR2   ADDR3   ADDR4   ADDR5   CITY    STATE   ZIP SSNO    PHONE1  PHONE2  EMAIL   NOTE    NOTEPAD FIRSTNAME   MIDINIT LASTNAME    SALUTATION  CUSTFLD1    CUSTFLD2    CUSTFLD3    CUSTFLD4    CUSTFLD5    CUSTFLD6    CUSTFLD7    CUSTFLD8    CUSTFLD9    CUSTFLD10   CUSTFLD11   CUSTFLD12   CUSTFLD13   CUSTFLD14   CUSTFLD15   HIDDEN  DELCOUNT
EMP 7/16/1998      6    1154716793     7    7/16/1998
```